# How to reset a sequence to a value above maximal index value used in a table?

Tags: oracle

In case, when newly created schema with empty tables and sequences set to initial values, is populated by inserts with IDs already set, sequences will stay unmodified (as expected).

How to correct sequences so they will return next available index (ID)?

```
select SEQ_TABLE.nextval from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running at least Oracle 19c, you can do this without dropping the sequence quite easily:

```
Alter sequence my_sequence restart minvalue 100;
```

You can obviously call this in PL/SQL using dynamic SQL (like you’re doing in your proposed answer)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following code:

```
DECLARE
   var NUMBER;
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'drop sequence SEQ_TABLE';
    SELECT MAX(ID) INTO var FROM TABLE;
    IF var IS NULL THEN
        var := 1;
    ELSE
        var := var + 1;
    END IF; 
    execute immediate 'create sequence SEQ_TABLE
        start with ' || var || '
        increment by 1
        maxvalue 999999999999999
        cache 5
        order';
        commit;
END;
/
```